# Sort a foreach loop numerically

Tags: php, sorting, foreach, opencart

Within opencart, i am developing the admin panel.

I want to show say, the top 10 stores and their respective visits.

at the moment, i have this information within a table and my php loop is this.

```
  <?php foreach ($stores as $store) { ?>
    <?php echo $store['name']?>
    <?php echo number_format($store['visitor'])?>
  <?php } ?>
```

This returns data in a big mess but the data IS there!

Alesso  20
Alice in Chains  32
Amy Winehouse  27
Avenged Sevenfold 136
Axewound  30
Axwell  6
Backstreet Boys  24

And so on.... for about 100 Different stores.

What i want to know is, in the foreach loop i wish to only display the top say, 10 stores.
the top stores with the most visits, now i have the data, but how do i go about sorting this in a foreach to only show the top 10?

Many thanks
Sean

Comment: How about you sort it in the query when fetching the data from the database? (Assuming this comes from a database)

Comment: Why are you beginning each line with an open php tag, and a closing php tag at the end of each line? You only need to open the php tag once, at the beginning of your script, and close it at the end of your script. Not after each line.

Comment: I think you can use array_multisort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: i know about the PHP tags on each line, thats how opencart uses alot of php, i just copied and pasted it, I will remove the inner php tags.

I'm unsure on how to use array_multisort

Comment: @ThomasPower Because probably this is inside of template file and in templates it's a good habit (and following of coding standard in OC templates) to enclose each PHP line with an open and close PHP tags... Imagine there is smarty or other templating tool used - in this case again each line will be enclosed in respective closing and opening sign/tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Update based on your code:

```
$limit=10;  
foreach ($stores as $key => $row) {
  $store[$key]  = $row['name'];
  $visitor[$key] = $row['visitor'];
}

array_multisort($visitor, SORT_DESC, $store, SORT_ASC, $stores);

$stores = array_chunk($stores, $limit);

foreach ($stores as $store) {
  echo $store['name'];      
  echo number_format($store['visitor']);        
}
```

Comment: I know how to use array_multisort if i hard code the data, but all i have is a Foreach loop getting the data for me, nowhere can i code the store name and visitors as its all dynamic.

I need to sort the store but still use the foreach loop

Comment: If you can foreach through the data, you can form the $data array ;)

Comment: Actually the $stores is the array likes my $data. You can try

Comment: `<?php 
 $i=0;
 $limit=10;
 foreach ($stores as $store) { 
  echo $store['name'];
  echo number_format($store['visitor']);
 if (++$i >=$limit) break;
 } 
?>`

This is what i have done so far, to show 10 results

Comment: Just apply my code to the $stores, I believe it works :). Try to var_export($stores) and you will see the structure of $stores.

Comment: I just tried but i get errors, im not a php person really lol.

Comment: There's no error now, it was a syntax thing, but here is SOME of the results of my var_export($stores)

`array ( 
0 => array ( 'store_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Store 1', 'url' => 'http://***.co.uk/', 'total_sale' => '0', 'total_price' => NULL, 'visitor' => '62', 'last_total_sale' => '0', 'last_total_price' => NULL, 'last_visitor' => '298', ), 

1 => array ( 'store_id' => '54', 'name' => 'Alesso', 'url' => 'http://***.co.uk/', 'total_sale' => '0', 'total_price' => NULL, 'visitor' => '20', 'last_total_sale' => '0', 'last_total_price' => NULL, 'last_visitor' => '49', )`

It goes on ALOT more than this

Comment: You can see, basically the structure of your $stores as the same as $data. Why you don't apply my code and you will see :-<.

Comment: i get an error

Undefined index: store in /home/tsadmin/public_html/admin/view/template/module/get_report.tpl on line 74

Line 74 is
`$store[$key]  = $row['store'];`

Comment: Sorry change $store[$key]  = $row['store']; ==> $store[$key]  = $row['name']; in the first foreach

Comment: OK so now its working, but the limit of 10 isnt, its showing all results

Comment: small modification:
$stores = array_chunk($stores, $limit);

Answer (score 1):

You have several solution :

- In the database use a Order By in your query and Select the first 10
- In PHP use this function http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php

It should give something like this :

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['visitor'] == $b['visitor']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['visitor'] < $b['visitor']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($store, "cmp");

$storeIndex= 0;
while($storeIndex< 10) {
        echo $store[storeIndex]['name'];
        echo number_format($store[storeIndex]['visitor']);

$storeIndex++;
}
```

Comment: I didn't test it but you see the idea here you have the comparaison of sorting function http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: the cmp function could be reduce to `return $a['visitor'] - $b['visitor']`

Comment: i copy pasted the code from the php website, but you are right, the function should return less than, equal to, or greater than zero